Adding vitest.d.env for custom matchers breaks vitest TS support
I wrote a custom matcher with expect.extend
expect.extend({
  toEqualIgnoringWhitespace(got: string, want: string) {
    return {
      pass: got.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ``) === want.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ``),
      message: () => `Even with whitespace removed, ${got} does not equal ${want}.`
    };
  }
});

And as recommended by the docs I added a vitest.d.env
interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toEqualIgnoringWhitespace: () => R
}

declare module 'vitest' {
  type Assertion<T = any> = CustomMatchers<T>
  interface AsymmetricMatchersContaining extends CustomMatchers {}
}

And I followed the docs:

Don't forget to include the ambient declaration file in your tsconfig.json.

  "include": ["vitest.d.ts","env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],

But now Typescript doesn't know about the rest of vitest. Using test.extend, use and task implicitly have any type.
const it = test.extend<{ row: EventRow }>({
  row: async ({ task }, use) => {  // errors here
    ...

It got clearer when I tried to import stuff from vitest and TS didn't recognize of the normal things like expect (I'm using globals for describe, it, etc; I tried these imports as a test). it only suggests the two things from the .d.env I pasted from the docs.
So it looks like I'm doing something wrong in either the tsconfig or the .d.env file but I don't know how to fix it.


I had the same exact issue as you, however I managed to get it working by including import or export keyword so that Typescript will know that this is a module augmentation instead of global declaration file thanks to this answer.
vitest.d.ts
import type { Assertion, AsymmetricMatchersContaining } from 'vitest' // This line is important even if imported values are not used!

interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toBeFoo: () => R
}

declare module 'vitest' {
  interface Assertion<T = any> extends CustomMatchers<T> {}
  interface AsymmetricMatchersContaining extends CustomMatchers {}
}

Since eslint complains that the imported files were not used, I solve it by using explicit empty export.
vitest.d.ts
export {} // Eslint don't complain, and everything works as expected, nice!

interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toBeFoo: () => R
}

declare module 'vitest' {
  interface Assertion<T = any> extends CustomMatchers<T> {}
  interface AsymmetricMatchersContaining extends CustomMatchers {}
}


Sharing the complete answer just in case:
vitest.d.ts
export {}

interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toBeFoo: () => R
}

declare module 'vitest' {
  interface Assertion<T = any> extends CustomMatchers<T> {}
  interface AsymmetricMatchersContaining extends CustomMatchers {}
}

vitest/custom-matchers.ts
import { expect } from 'vitest'

expect.extend({
  toBeFoo(received, expected) {
    const { isNot } = this
    return {
      // do not alter your "pass" based on isNot. Vitest does it for you
      pass: received === 'foo',
      message: () => `${received} is${isNot ? ' not' : ''} foo`
    }
  }
})

vitest.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    setupFiles: ['./vitest/custom-matchers.ts'],
  },
})

tsconfig.json
{
  // ...
  "include": ["...", "vitest.d.ts"]
}

